# How get Application object in FlutterActivity?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a third-party native android SDK i need initiate the SDK first

How I can get an application object? I tried `this.application` but I'm getting an error

I'm not an expert in Android Native

I tried

`override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {`

`Sdk.initialize(application = this.application);`

`}`

but I'm getting an error so my guess is that is not the correct form, something like name is null